# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lasound

Tags: c, makefile, snowboy

While using the `make` command on [snowboy](https://snowboy.kitt.ai/) in the folder [snowboy/examples/C/](https://github.com/Kitt-AI/snowboy/tree/master/examples/C) I got the following errors

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack_atlas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lasound
```

I have manage to solve all of them exapt `-lasound` with the command

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

How can I add the missing library `-lasound`

Answer (score 6):

There is commented line inside the file `install_portaudio.sh` which states

> ```
> # On linux systems, we only build with ALSA, so make sure you install it using
> # e.g.:
> #   sudo apt-get -y install libasound2-dev
> ```

So just run the command `sudo apt-get -y install libasound2-dev` in the terminal and it should work.